# how to set read/write permissions on ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm new to ActiveMQ so please bear with me if my question seem dumb :D

I have installed activemq on a CentOS machine and I'm connecting to it for writing to the qeueue and consuming from the queue through the admin user (which I dont think its the ideal way). I'm wondering if I can create a user for read only to read (consume) from the queue and another user for write only or just a single user who has read/write privileges only so this user wont be able to delete the queue or do anything that its not supposed to do.

I tried youtube and checked out [activemq security](http://activemq.apache.org/security.html) documentation which talks about simple plugin and tried it but I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing or reading the right resource?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is the correct resource to start off with , if you want to write a custom plugin you can also do that in AMQ it is really quite very simple.Your use case specifically is about the "Controlling Access To Temporary Destinations" section of that page .

Comment: @Sundar, thanks a lot for your reply! Could you please provide more details? Should I edit the activemq.xml file by adding temDest to it? and just set the user.properties and groups.properties? will I need to use jaas?

Comment: Yes once you setup the users you can add the group of users to the queue   <authorizationEntry queue="TEST.Q" read="users" write="users" admin="users" />

Comment: @Sundar I think you should explain a bit to user as answer not comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ works on different login and authorization modules , by default it picks up the PropertyLoginModule in the karaf realm.  This is the admin user you are talking about. /etc/users.properties file contains these users and groups.

For Authorization you have plugins in the activemq.xml which can provide fine grained control on the Queues , Topics , Advisories and temporary queues.

The idea is to group users and provide them with read / write /admin access to Queues , you can specify all the queues your application has one by one , group them with wildchars ( as per AMQ doc ).

You can edit the users.properties file and add a few more users and tie up these users in authentication and authorization sections.

Also there are LDAP and SSL modules available for authorization and authentication.